# Explain the function Middleware

Tags: javascript, middleware

Can anybody give me tutorial how this function is working i am not able to understand how this function is working. How this.go function actually working. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
var Middleware = function() {};

Middleware.prototype.use = function(fn) {
  var self = this;

  this.go = (function(stack) {
    return function(next) {
      stack.call(self, function() {
        fn.call(self, next.bind(self));
      });
    }.bind(this);
  })(this.go);
};

Middleware.prototype.go = function(next) {
  next();
};
```

USAGE

```
var middleware = new Middleware();

middleware.use(function(next) {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.hook1 = true;
    console.log('a')
    next();
  }, 10);
});

middleware.use(function(next) {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.hook2 = true;
    console.log('b')
    next();
  }, 10);
});

var start = new Date();
middleware.go(function() {
  console.log(this.hook1); // true
  console.log(this.hook2); // true
  console.log(new Date() - start); // around 20
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this code seems to be to build up a sequence of functions, which will then be run one after the other.

The `go` method's job is to run some code. If you've never called `use`, then `go` will run the specified code immediately, with no complications.

The `use` method lets you insert additional steps to be run. When you call `use`, the original go method is replaced with a new method. That new method will call the old go method, followed by your custom method. If use is called multiple times, this builds up a sequence of functions. The functions will be called in the order they were passed in to use. The next function starts running when the previous function calls `next()`.

---

A lot of the complication of the code comes from making sure that the value of `this` stays what it's expected to be. If that wasn't a requirement, then `use` could be rewritten like this:

```
Middleware.prototype.use = function(fn) {
  const oldGo = this.go;
  this.go = next => oldGo(() => fn(next))
}
```